# I need to force a click within a hta script

Tags: html, hta

I'm a good scripter, but not a developer.  Can someone please advise how to force a click event to this line of code, or to force the "installergui_startinstallation" routine to kick off automatically.  Thanks.  Here is the line that takes the click command:

```
<button id=butStartInstallation onClick="InstallerGUI_startInstallation">Install</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button id=butCancel            onClick="self.close()">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: Might to want to show a little more code, there isn't much to work with here. Also, which button would you like to click to happen on?

Comment: The install button is the one I want to activate automatically, that kicks off the installer.

Comment: ok good good, we are getting warmer! Nice job adding some code! Now is this what `HTA` is? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application

Comment: Yes, it's a file format used as an installation interface, it has a bunch of code to determine what prerequisites need to be installed, etc.  The rubber meets the road at the "install" button.  I'm trying to automate this so no user intervention is needed, so I want to force that "install" click at that point.

Comment: Here is the whole installation interface

Answer (score 0):

So I am a Javascript man, and it looks like in HTA you can have a `<script type="text/javascript">`  so if that is the case then have a shot at this

```
<button id="butStartInstallation" onClick="InstallerGUI_startInstallation">Install</button>
<button id="butCancel" onClick="self.close()">Cancel</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function doClick() {
        document.getElementById("butStartInstallation").click();
    }
    doClick();
</script>
```

If that isn't enough [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997163/how-to-programatically-click-a-button-thats-loaded-from-another-page) is another resource for you to check out. They use Javascript in that example

If you are using VBScript then [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344960/how-to-cause-button-click-event-when-enter-is-pressed-in-an-hta-application) is another example for you to check out

Comment: I added that code in, and it doesn't error, but it doesn't click the button.  I'm not a javascripter at all, thanks for the help, this has to be getting me close.

Comment: @OleDaHammer Ok I edited the post, I added one line just below the function `doClick()` which calls the function. Give that a shot

Comment: Looks like that did the trick.  Thanks so much for the assistance.  If you ever need help packaging software installs, let me know, that's my expertise lies.  Sometimes I run into funky stuff like this trying to create unattended installs that is just outside of my wheelhouse.  THANKS!

Comment: For sure! I'm happy to help out!

Comment: If you could accept this answer and upvote, I would really appreciate it